# huponexit off and ampersand inputted - but program still close

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, centos

```
[oracle@centos1 ~]$ shopt | grep hupon
huponexit       off

[oracle@centos1 ~] sqldeveloper & -- program is being ran
```

With the above, it is already stated that there will be no hup signal sent on exit. But when I close the shell, the program still gets closed.

Why ?

Comment: Is `sqldeveloper` still attached to the tty and closing when it goes away? Does using `nohup sqldeveloper &` work?

Comment: @EtanReisner using nohup will works. But what i don't understand is my huponexit is already off. So why does & not works.

Comment: If you use the manual redirections to close stdin, stdout and stderr when running `sqldeveloper` it still closes when you exit the terminal? Can you run it that way and then run `ls -l /proc/<pid of sqldeveloper>/fd` and show us the output?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because `sqldeveloper` is attached to the terminal. `nohup` works because it detaches the command automatically — see this excerpt from `nohup(1)`:

> If  standard  input  is a terminal, redirect it from /dev/null.  If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise.  If standard error is a terminal, redirect it to standard output.  To save output to FILE, use 'nohup COMMAND > FILE'.

It should work without `nohup` if you do it by hand — try for example:

```
sqldeveloper < /dev/null &> /dev/null &
```

Comment: same, with your command, when i close the terminal, sqldeveloper get close as well

Comment: It seems that stopped jobs are killed regardless of the `huponexit` option. After running the program in background check out the output of the `jobs` command. If the process is stopped, please write about it — there has to be a reason for that.

Comment: [oracle@centos1 ~]$ shopt | grep hup
huponexit       off
[oracle@centos1 ~]$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sqldeveloper &
[oracle@centos1 ~]$

Comment: When i exit the terminal, the program still get closed.